# gulp-sass throw error on file convertion from scss to css

Tags: css, sass, gulp

I am trying to convert multiple `scss` files in to single `css file`. the `main.scss` file imports multiple files with `variable.scss` file as well. when i convert to css file I am getting an error as:

```
[09:46:00] Using gulpfile ~\722333\Projects\AOS.Core\UI\assets\gulpfile.js
[09:46:00] Starting 'styles'...
[09:46:00] Finished 'styles' after 25 ms
Error in plugin "sass"
Message:
    styles\form.scss
Error: Undefined variable: "$color-red".
        on line 53 of styles/form.scss
>>     color: $color-red;
   -----------^
```

how to fix this?

here is my gulp task:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

gulp.task('styles', async function () {
    gulp.src('styles/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
         .pipe(sass({ outputStyle: 'compressed' }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./css/'));
});
```

my main.scss file:

```
@import "variables.scss";
@import "global.scss";
@import "fonts.scss";

//resets;-
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: $font-regular, sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.625rem;
  color: $text-primary;
  background: $color-white;
}
```

Comment: I see your error is in `form.scss` Either that file must import the `variables.scss` file itself or `form.scss` must be inported into `main.scss` to get access to `$color-red` (which I assume is in `variables.scss`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In Short:**

Partials’ filenames should start with an underscore.

Rename partials to `_variables.scss`, `_global.scss`, `_fonts.scss` and update `main.scss` to:

```
@import "variables";
@import "global";
@import "fonts";
```

**Full explanation:**

The build is failing because sass is trying to compile `form.scss` as `form.css` and can’t find reference to `$color-red`.

From Sass-Lang.com:

> As a convention, Sass files that are only meant to be imported, not
> compiled on their own, begin with `_` (as in `_code.scss`). These are
> called partials, and they tell Sass tools not to try to compile those
> files on their own. You can leave off the _ when importing a partial.

https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/import#partials